# How to redirect the response of Html forms

Tags: html, forms, redirect

I have a HTML page like follows. Once user enter the button, server will send some response to this page. But i need to redirect the response to other server/page, without displaying it on the screen.

```
<html>
  <body>
     <form name="hack" action="http://localhost/get_servers" method="GET">
           <input type="submit" value="Get Details"/>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can i achieve it without changing server side code.

Comment: What server language are you using? c#, php, java...?

Comment: Why can you not change any server side code?

Comment: @Nikhil What you trying to do ? .If you want Redirection just put this on button click event and send your required data.

Comment: I am testing Cross Site Request Forgery attack for my application. ie: Invoking some calls/api with single click and steal some data without user's knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

So you might want to use ajax to submit the post. Suppose you are using jQuery, then you will have the following code:

```
$(function(){
  // capture form submit event and use ajax post to submit it
  $('form').submit(function(){
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(response) {
      // do whatever you want with the response.
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks Green.  Can you please give complete code, ie: how to incorporate this snippet in my code.

Comment: If you explain exactly what you want to do I'm sure people will help!

Comment: I need to create a simple html page with a button. 
When ever user click that button, some calls should goto server and server will send response back.
I need to send that response to another server without printing same on screen.

Answer (score 0):

USE POST instead of GET, Hope this help